# RMagick error on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm getting the following error when running rake db:seed:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Image
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError, 
Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

I've never seen this error before so I'm not quite sure what to make of it. The only model that has the Image object in it is the slider.rb:

```
class Slider < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
      thumb: '100x100>',
      medium: '300x300>'
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

But again, slider might not be related to the error.

Any help would be great, thanks!!!